# Adding parameters to teamcity project causes build agent to no longer be compatible

Tags: teamcity

I have TeamCity 2019.1.2 running on a CentOS 7 box, server and the agent installed on the same box.

I am trying to set up an environment variable within a project with the value of the teamcity property `%teamcity.build.branch%` with the name `env.branch` so that I can use this within a build step.

The build runs perfectly find without the parameter but as soon as the parameter is adding when I try and add a build to the queue the agent is then no longer compatible.

When I look at the build queue it says there's one item in the queue but no build agents available and under the incompatible agents it states the following:

```
implicit requirements: teamcity.build.branch defined in Parameters: env.branch
```

Is there something I need to do to make this work or am I misunderstanding how this works?

**UPDATE**

Below is a screenshot showing how I've added the parameter

[image: Parameter Build Configuration View]

Comment: If the value of your `env.branch` parameter is the same as the value of built-in property `teamcity.build.branch`, maybe you don't need to define your own parameter in the first place and can use the property directly? E.g. everywhere where you'd use `if [ ${branch} == "master" ] ; then ...` you could rewrite that as `if [ %teamcity.build.branch% == "master" ] ; then ...`

Comment: I did try doing that originally but I get the same problem as soon as I add a teamcity property directly into the command line on the build step. I thought maybe adding a parameter would get round the problem but apparently not :(

Comment: can you please share the build step commands that use the `env.branch` parameter or the builtin property? Also, I assume that you have defined this environment variable explicitly under Build Configuration Settings -> Parameters, correct?

Comment: @KMZ I've added a screenshot showing the parameter configuration. I don't get as a far as attempting to use the parameter in the command line build step as the build breaks with just the parameter. When I was trying to use the TC property directly it was something like `sudo mkdir /home/teamcity/releases/ProjectName/%teamcity.build.branch%`

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem. Most likely reason is that in the VCS Root Settings you didn't setup the branch specification and left it empty, specifying only the default branch. In such case Teamcity doesn't create the `%teamcity.build.branch%` property, and this is why referencing it anywhere in build steps or in other properties' definitions makes your agents incompatible. To fix this, use `+:refs/heads/*` as a branch specification, and see if that solves your problem. If it does, you don't even need to define your own variable `env.branch`, and can use the built-in property directly.

Comment: btw, here's  the [official Teamcity documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#PredefinedBuildParameters-Branch-RelatedParameters) regarding `%teamcity.build.branch%` property.

Comment: Thanks I still couldn't get it to work for some reason but I've found another way to do what I want to do so I should be OK. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Thank you, @KMZ! TeamCity could have shown a better error message